# How to convert a list of slash separated strings into a nested dictionary?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, parsing, dictionary

I have a list of data in the following format:

```
viewsList = [
  "/list/devicetype",
  "/list/client/devicetype",
  "/list/client/site/devicetype",
  "/list/privileges",
  "/list/client/serviceusage",
  "/list/client/site/serviceusage",
  "/list/client/license"
]
```

Out of this, I want to create a dictionary in the following format:

```
viewsDict = {
    "list": {
        "devicetype": {},
        "client": {
            "devicetype": {},
            "site": {
                "devicetype": {},
                "serviceusage": {}
            },
            "serviceusage": {},
            "license": {}
        },
        "privileges": {}
    }
}
```

#### What I have tried so far:

I have displayed the code below so that it executes successfully. It prints out the first step in my thought process.

If I managed to produce 7 separate dictionaries, one for each element in 'viewsList', would I then be able to merge all of them without overwriting?:

```
def url_views():
    viewsList = [
        "/list/devicetype",
        "/list/client/devicetype",
        "/list/client/site/devicetype",
        "/list/privileges",
        "/list/client/serviceusage",
        "/list/client/site/serviceusage",
        "/list/client/license"
    ]    
    viewsDict = {}
    for eachView in viewsList:
        #viewsDict.update(...
        build_dict(eachView[1:].split("/")) #) I know update() won't work here 
                                               # because it will just overight
                                               # keys which are supposed to have
                                               # multiple nested dictionaries 

def build_dict(eachViewSplit):

    # Need to do something here to convert each line into a dictionary
    print eachViewSplit # Printing this line for diagnostics purposes
    #return buildDict


print url_views()
```

#### Logic of operations:

I have worked out the logic I require, all I need help with is how to codify these steps:

```
>>> viewsDict = {}
>>> viewsDict["list"] = {}
>>> viewsDict["list"]["devicetype"] = {}
>>> viewsDict["list"]["client"] = {}
>>> viewsDict["list"]["client"]["devicetype"] = {}
>>> viewsDict["list"]["client"]["site"] = {}
>>> viewsDict["list"]["client"]["site"]["devicetype"] = {}
>>> viewsDict["list"]["privileges"] = {}
>>> viewsDict["list"]["client"]["serviceusage"] = {}
>>> viewsDict["list"]["client"]["site"]["serviceusage"] = {}
>>> viewsDict["list"]["client"]["license"] = {}
>>> print viewsDict
```

This prints out a dictionary equivalent to the one listed above.

Comment: I suggest you take the "what I've tried so far" and move it to an answer so that the question simply states the problem. (I've no idea why some people thing the problem statement isn't clear. It gives an input and expected output, and is missing only a call to assertEqual to be a unit test.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def parse(lines):
    result = dict()

    for line in lines:
        cur_dict = result
        for field in line.strip("/").split("/"):
            cur_dict = cur_dict.setdefault(field, {})

    return result
```

`dict.setdefault` is equivalent to:

```
def setdefault(self, key, default):
    try:
        return self[key]
    except KeyError:
        self[key] = default
        return default
```

So for each field in the "/"-delimited string, we dive into the dictionary and create empty dicts where appropriate. Then when we bump back to the next line we start back from the root.

Comment: This provides the incorrect format for the dictionary. I ran your code on my input and got this as output:

    `{
        "license": {},
        "privileges": {},
        "list": {},
        "site": {},
        "client": {},
        "devicetype": {},
        "serviceusage": {}
    }`

Comment: @DeanKayton You might be looking at the original revision. I made a rudimentary error. Refresh the page and you'll get `{'list': {'devicetype': {}, 'client': {'devicetype': {}, 'site': {'devicetype': {}, 'serviceusage': {}}, 'serviceusage': {}, 'license': {}}, 'privileges': {}}}`. Although I did edit the post 5 minutes before your comment!

Comment: Thanks, you are right. This is working! Edit: Looks like it took me 5min to test your solution, it's been a long day...

Comment: I ended up asking a related question but more to do with interpreting the string as a dictionary call. The answer that I provide there uses a specific method asked for in the question.

It happens to apply to this question too.

Here is the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063043/how-to-interpret-a-string-to-define-a-dictionary-call/) for reference sake.

Should I post it as an answer to this question too?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out an alternate solution to my own question.

```
import json
import dpath.util

def build_dict(viewsDict, viewsList):
    for views in viewsList:
        viewsDict = new_keys(viewsDict, views)
    return viewsDict

def new_keys(viewsDict, views):
    dpath.util.new(viewsDict, views, {})
    return viewsDict

viewsDict = {}
viewsList = [
    "/list/devicetype",
    "/list/client/devicetype",
    "/list/client/site/devicetype",
    "/list/privileges",
    "/list/client/serviceusage",
    "/list/client/site/serviceusage",
    "/list/client/license"
]

print json.dumps(build_dict(viewsDict, viewsList), indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```