# How to interpret a string to define a dictionary call?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to pass in to a function, a string which will be interpreted to determine the desired dictionary call required to update a dictionary.

Here is an example of what I have so far, hard-coded:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

def default_dict():
    return defaultdict(default_dict)

def build_dict():
    d["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"]["e"]["f"].update({})
    d["a"]["b"]["c1"]["d1"].update({})
    return json.dumps(d)

d = default_dict()
print build_dict()
```

But to be useful to me I want to pass in strings to the build_dict() function. Lets call it 's':

```
for s in ["a/b/c/d/e/f", "a/b/c1/d1"]:
    print build_dict(s)
```

Which should print the following (exactly as it does in the example I hard-coded:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "d": {
                    "e": {
                        "f": {}
                    }
                }
            },
            "c1": {
                "d1": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have to make sure that multiple branches are supported in the way they are (as far as I have tested) in my hard-coded example.

**What I am currently attempting:**

- Midway through constructing this question I found out about dpath, "A python library for accessing and searching dictionaries via /slashed/paths ala xpath". It looks exactly what I need so if I successfully work it out, I will post an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a solution to my own question.

```
import json
import dpath.util

def build_dict(viewsDict, viewsList):
    for views in viewsList:
        viewsDict = new_keys(viewsDict, views)
    return viewsDict

def new_keys(viewsDict, views):
    dpath.util.new(viewsDict, views, {})
    return viewsDict

viewsDict = {}
viewsList = [
    "a/b/c/d/e/f",
    "a/b/c1/d1"
]

print json.dumps(build_dict(viewsDict, viewsList), indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This builds a dict based on sequence of paths and passes your test case.

It builds a dictionary from up to down, adding a new keys if they are missing, and updating an existing dictionary when they are present.

```
def build_dict(string_seq):
    d = {}
    for s in string_seq:
        active_d = d
        parts = s.split("/")
        for p in parts:
            if p not in active_d:
                active_d[p] = {}
            active_d = active_d[p]
    return d


expected = {
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "d": {
                    "e": {
                        "f": {}
                    }
                }
            },
            "c1": {
                "d1": {}
            }
        }
    }
}

string_seq = ["a/b/c/d/e/f", "a/b/c1/d1"]
result = build_dict(string_seq)
assert result == expected
```